# How to have a method that was found true to display another method underneath? Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, random

I am a novice, I figured out all of my code except one part.
Fake radio station
I need to display a method that contains a message underneath a method that has been found true.

```
        if (seek.equals("down")) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            int rmdTest = rmd.nextInt(10);
            found = rmdTest > 6;
                if (found) {
                if (rmdTest == 7)
                    foundStation(98.9, found);
                if (rmdTest == 8)
                    foundStation(100.3, found);
                if (rmdTest == 9)
                    foundStation(107.9, found);

           //This prints out that station is found, but it needs 
           //message that displays the callsign/what's playing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question, but think you'd benefit from a more OOP approach, eg:

```
Radio radio = new Radio();
Station station = radio.getCurrentStation();
Callsign callsign = station.getCallsign();
```

That way the "found to be true" part of your question is handled by `getCurrentStation` and the "message underneth" part is in `getCallsign` or whatever format message the display needs, perhaps methods to update such as `display.show(callsign)` or preferably event driven.